# Error opening SQL Script

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a database running on SQL Server 2008 R2. It has been running fine for over a year and a half. Unfortunately, the application vendor have just informed us that they only support the application on SQL 2005, and can no longer support us unless we migrate.

I have exported the entire database (data and schema) to a script with the target version set to 2005. The resulting file is just over 5GB. However, I'm unable to open the script on the target server, as I receive the following error:

> error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component

I know this is not much to go on and is a generic error. Unfortunately there's nothing else in the logs. Is this something anyone has encountered before?

Comment: Does this happen when running the script? Or opening the script in SSMS?

Comment: When opening the script.

Comment: See this: http://www.sqlnewsgroups.net/sqlserver/t17291-vs-2005-sql-server-2005-remote-debugging-issue.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/51ef4b81-6677-4e2d-8b80-648633cf699e) .
Looks like you're running into address space limitation, and the suggested resolution is to use sqlcmd.

Comment: Many thanks. I did in fact use sqlcmd as a workaround (without knowing why it wasn't working) - unfortunately it has it's own limitations (I really needed to edit the script to change the file paths).

Comment: I run into this issue a while back. use Textpad, UltraEdit or JuJuEdit; they handle large files well.